# Why is it necessary for the Fault-tolerant error correction condition to take into account two qubit errors?

Tags: error-correction, fault-tolerance

The Fault-tolerant error correction (FTEC) condition states that for a code distance of 3, if there are no input errors, even if up to one gate fault (including a two qubit error occurring on a two qubit gate) occurs within the circuit, the output after error correction will have at most one data error remaining. Why is it unacceptable to have more than one data error remaining after a gate fault that includes not just one qubit error, but also two qubit error? I understand about the one qubit error, but since a code of distance 3 can only correct up to weight one errors, it seems to me that even if a two qubit error becomes two or more data errors, it would still be acceptable as an FTEC condition.

Comment: Hi. Could you clarify which fault-tolerant error correction condition you are exactly referring to, as there are different conditions (given your text I am not sure to very precisely see which one you are referring to). "since a code of distance 3 can only correct up to weight one errors, it seems to me that even if a two qubit error becomes two or more data errors, it would still be acceptable as an FTEC condition.": if a single logical qubit has these two data errors, this is too late as it will be uncorrectable given the code distance [...]

Comment: [...]If these data errors occur on two different logical qubits because they interacted with a logical cNOT: you are fine (each logical qubit is corrected independently). Which situation are you referring to?

Comment: p6 of the paper arxiv:quant-ph/0504218 says that “If a 1-EC contains at most one fault, it takes an input with no errors to an output with at most one error.” This “one fault” contains two qubit error of CNOT gate. I am referring to a situation where a single logical exists. I extract it’s syndrome using syndrome measurement circuit such as Shor’s method, Steane’s method, or Knill’s method.

Comment: What matters is that this 1 fault on a cNOT in the 1-Ec might indeed introduce two errors (because it makes 2 physical qubit interact). However these two errors must not be on the logical data qubit. For instance it would be acceptable to have 1 error on the ancilla doing syndrome extraction, and 1 error on the data qubit if after the syndrome extraction and correction the data qubit contains one error only (up to a stabilizer). This is what the axiom asks for. Having 2 errors on the logical data qubit is unacceptable as  it goes beyond the maximum number of error the code can correct (1 here)

Comment: Basically: why do you say that having 2 errors on the logical data qubit would be acceptable? In practice you should never allow for that.

Comment: I understand what you say. But, I don’t say having 2 errors on the logical data qubit would be acceptable. I mean that “one fault” should only include  one qubit errors, not include two qubit errors. Assuming a one fault includes a two-qubit error, I understand that only one data error should remain after error correction. However, I don't understand why we're assuming a one fault would include a two-qubit error in the first place.

Comment: I believe the meaning of fault tolerance is that correctable errors should not be amplified during the error correction process. Therefore, I think that the only errors we should assume to occur are one-qubit errors, which are correctable. I wonder if it's unnecessary to consider two-qubit errors that may occur with CNOT, since they could potentially be uncorrectable errors in the first place.

Comment: For an $n$-qubit gate we should in general assume that one fault produced by this gate can introduce one error on each qubit it involves. Imagine that during the Hamiltonian evolution of the gate, "in the middle" of the evolution a bit-flip occurs on the first qubit of this gate. Because you make a many-body interaction, this error might propagate over all the qubits involved in the gate. This is one of the reasons why we should assume that one fault in an $n$-qubit gate can introduce error on each qubit it is applied to.